# Python - Standard scaler fit on transform on partial data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Having the following DF:

```
   A   B    c
0  1   1   21
1  2  12  122
2  3   3   23
3  4  14  124
4  5   5   25
```

My "train set" has been transformed using StandardScaler. The transformed features have the following values:

```
array([[-1.41421356, -1.17669681, -0.85696442],
       [-0.70710678,  0.98058068,  1.20383097],
       [ 0.        , -0.78446454, -0.81615659],
       [ 0.70710678,  1.37281295,  1.24463879],
       [ 1.41421356, -0.39223227, -0.77534876]])
```

Scaler is saved as a PKL file, and it is used at inference time to transform features. However, on some occasions, I only want certain features, for example only the `A` column. As the scaler was trained on a different shape, it is unable to transform just the `A`, and thus an error arises.

```
ValueError: X has 1 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input.
```

As a result, I'm transforming the data and selecting the feature afterward, as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[1,12,3,14,5],'c':[21,122,23,124,25]})
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(df.values)

# scaler.transform(df[['A']].values) #this line will fail with ValueError: X has 1 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input.

scaler.transform(df.values).T[0]
```

Is there a more elegant way to do so?

**Update**
In some cases I don't even have the entire DF but just the raw column, so I can't use the scaler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the scaler [API](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) and [the code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L991) there seems to be no way of applying on a column subsample with the sklearn class. You could write your own class taking an optional column mask at transform time and applying it before the scaling. For instance

```py
class PartialStandardScaler(StandardScaler):

    def transform(self, X, column_mask=None):
        if column_mask is None:
             return super().transform(X)
        return (X[:,column_mask] - self.mean_[column_mask])/self.scale_[column_mask]
```

and in your case you could have

```py
scaler.transform(df.values, column_mask=[True,False,False])
```

You could allow the column mask to be passed as a list of column indices too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, I'm trying to avoid transforming all the data frame. I'll update my question.

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz I did look at your update, still I am confused, in the example I gave, I am not transforming the whole data frame, only the first column (the other two are getting "dropped" before the scaler is applied). What more do you need?

Comment: My bad, I see your solution is what I need, thanks again!